# Install ROS Groovy on Raspberry PI: catkin_make_isolated import error

Tags: python, raspberrypi, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My intention is to get Groovy running on Raspberry PI so I can work with ROS_NXT. I am trying to follow the guide:

http://wiki.ros.org/nxt

I run into issues while trying to install Groovy on raspberry pi using the following guide:

http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

I get to item: 6. Build the Catkin Workspace

I attempt to run the following command:

Invoke catkin_make_isolated:

```
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

This results in the command not being found.

I then alter the command to run the python script named catkin_make_isolated which on my installation is located at:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkin_make_isolated

This results in the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 11, in <module> from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated, colorize line, extract_cmake_and_make_arguments
ImportError: No module named catkin.builder
```

I have tried:

1. command: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-catkin-pkg`
2. running the commend to invoke `catkin_make_isolated` (minus `sudo`) after: `sudo bash`

I am obviously new to this and struggling to get past this error. Any help would be very welcome.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223525/install-ros-groovy-on-raspberry-pi:-catkin_make_isolated-import-error/) by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try
[ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org/projects/2014/11/17/ROS-on-EV3/)

if you have an EV3 this should  be easy, you connect the PI with the EV3 Brick over USB-Network,

run the Ros Master on the PI and and the Sensor nodes on the Brick

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-01-05**:
I have a Lego Mindstorms NXT (the prior generation) I am afraid. I will keep this in mind for the future in case I have to go that way. Are you aware of any issues with connecting to the NXT?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2016-01-05**:
I like lego, and i think connecting Lego with ros is greate, this ist the bridge from toy to research. Do you use the NXT brick or the PiBrick?. Is it possible to use an PI2 it would make it more standard, standard Ubuntu.More support, ros works from stock.

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-01-05**:
I am trying to figure out the installation so i can connect a raspberry pi model A to connect to an NXT. The  PI brick would be nice but I have an NXT brick and a raspberry pi on hand.

I do agree is that it would be a wonderful (and affordable) way to understand the workings of ROS.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-07**:
Ah ok.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi is an option, but may not be less work than getting groovy to work, but if you are getting it to talk to your laptop which is using indigo it is much better to have them both using the same ROS version

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2016-01-07**:
Yesterday I make a clean install of ros indigo an a fresh rasbian Jessy lite installation.
Following the [instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

An the compilation worked. I tried the comm packets. But it toke a long time

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-01-07**:
I will have to keep Jessie in mind. However, in the case of using ROS-NXT on the Raspberry PI (original PI not 2) needs at least the Mobile install.

Thanks for replying though, I am looking for ideas.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2016-01-07**:
i tryed rosinstall_generator robot mobile perception nxt_ros --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-nxt.rosinstall

and the output was
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: mobile, nxt_ros

i see there is no official nxt_ros catkin build.

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-01-07**:
I am told that there are some unofficial catkin-ized clones of the original repository on GitHub.

I got this from a comment from a comment at:

http://wiki.ros.org/sig/NXT